# How to use large with averageif

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently using this formula in excel to calculate the average value of Column W

=IF(C2=FALSE,ROUNDUP(AVERAGEIF(F:F,F2,W:W),0),"-")

Now i would like to know the average of the second and thrid highest value instead of average. How do in incorporate the large function into Column W?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear-- you just want the average of the second and third largest values?

Simply `=(LARGE(W:W, 2)+LARGE(W:W, 3))/2`

If you want the average of the second and third largest that meet certain criteria, try

`=(LARGE(FILTER(W:W, F:F=F2),2)+LARGE(FILTER(W:W, F:F=F2),3))/2`